# How to forecast data in Excel for monotonic data sets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a monotonically increasing data set in Excel, and I want to forecast future values of this data. Since it is monotonic, the usual forecasting functions (e.g. `FORECAST.LINEAR`, `FORECAST.ETS`, and `TREND`) will underestimate the data if it has a positive second derivative (concave up).

[Here is a screenshot of a graph I have to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Bi7.png). The blue line is the actual data, the orange line is forecasted data using the `FORECAST.LINEAR` function. A better forecast would never have a value less than the latest known value, but you can see in that graph that it is underestimating for the last third or so of the data points.

Is there a way to forecast the data which accounts for that data being monotonic?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the orange line is a running forecast (i.e. each and every point on the orange line is a forecast of all the blue actual data before it.

I tend to think of forecast.linear as is giving you straight line segments with slopes approximately equal to the average slope of all the data before it. Now in your monotone function, the pieces of data with zero slope, is effectively (and correctly so) lowering this average slope. While, as a short term forecast, it is way off, is it also taking into account the statistical probability of more flat curved data showing up based on past occurrences.

Consider the following. The lower bound of your next estimate y(t+dt) is obviously just y(t). The upper bound could be infinity, but more likely y(t+dt) = m * dt + y(t), with m = max{dy/dt of all prior data points}. Your linear forecast would be close to the average of those two extremes.

If you want to rather ignore past "flattened curves", perhaps considering using only the last *x* number of data points for the forecast. You could perhaps estimate the length of *x* based on the average number of data points the slope tends to stay roughly the same.